# convertir un array en entero

Tags: php, array, string

se puede convertir cada posicion de un array en entero y guardarlo en variables distintas. y como se haria. yo encontre que una variable string pdia convertirse a entero asi :

```
$VarInt= (int)$varString;
```

asi que lo intente de esta manera:

```
 for ($i=0; $i < $sizeArrAdv ; $i++) {


 $Yhire_date  [$i] = $this->ol_model->getyearHire($arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"]);
 $Mhire_date [$i] = $this->ol_model->getmonthHire($arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"]);


    $Yhire_daten[$i]= (int)$Yhire_date[$i];


                            }
```

pero no me funciona , lo imprimo y me sale (1) cuando el año es 2017.

```
$Yhire_date  [$i] = $this->ol_model->getyearHire($arrayAdvocates[$i]["roster_salesforcename"]);
```

esta linea va a un metodo en el modelo el cual hace una consulta y solo selecciona el año de una fecha usando year($date) y lo devuelve como un array, quiero convertir ese año en un int para poder hacer operaciones con el

objeto json de el array $Yhire_date:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ves el año siempre esta en la posicion [0]del array

esto me da con:

```
 $Yhire_daten[$i]= idate('Y',$Yhire_date[$i][0]['year']);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta con esto: $Yhire_daten[$i]= idate('Y', $Yhire_date[$i]);

Comment: me sale este error Message: idate() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given

Comment: Parece que el contenido de `$Yhire_date` no es el que suponen y hay un array anidado.

Comment: si esque  $yhire_date es un array que en su posicion [0] tiene otro array que n su posicion ['month'] tendria el año,me toco hacerlo asi porque la consulta devuelve un array

Comment: Entonces solo reemplaza $Yhire_date[$i] con el indice correcto que contiene la fecha que deseas cambiar.

Comment: no me da, te voy a montar una imagen en la pregunta con el reultado al imprimir $Yhire_date como un objeto json que se ve mas ordenado

Comment: ya probaste con $Yhire_date[$i][0]['year']

Comment: agregue otra imagen imprimiendo lo que dio con tu linea @alanfcm , porue cambia por 1970 si es 2017